# Cannot locate node in package

Tags: ros, node, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to run a server?
I cloned the package dmp and saved it in my sandbox. when I roslaunch the dmp node, I get the error

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [dmp/dmp_server]: can't locate node [dmp_server] in package [dmp]
```

Must I add something in CMakeList.txt before I launch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152021/cannot-locate-node-in-package/) by [Ros_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/14601/ros_newbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2014-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you build your workspace before trying to launch the node? ROS C++ nodes are just regular Linux binaries, which you need to build by compiling their source code. <s>As you are refering to a sandbox, I'm assuming you're on Hydro, using `catkin`. In that case, go to the toplevel directory of your sandbox (ie: probably `catkin_ws`) after having sourced your `setup.bash` file, then:</s>

```
$ catkin_make
```

This should build your workspace. Then (after sourcing the `setup.bash` in the `devel` directory) try to launch the node again.

---

Edit: all wrong: apparently `dmp` is a rosbuild package, so instead of using `catkin`, you should build it using `rosmake`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ros_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/14601/ros_newbie/) on 2014-04-11**:
thanks. yes. Its a rosbuild package.